# How to measure the training error when using svmtrain

Tags: matlab, svm

I am using the bioinformatics toolbox to apply support vector machine. I am using svmtrain command  to training my classifier, but I don't know how can I measure the training error or where can I find the predicted output for this phase.
Can anyone help me please, 
Best Regards,

Comment: After training, you run svmclassify with the same training data and compare the returned predicted labels with the original labels. You can simply count number of mismatches. If you want to find cross validation error, it is something else though.

Comment: Like @Zoran said there is a difference between the cross-validation error and mismatches, but for more informations read directly on LibSVM website. And I recommend to have a look on that example [Matlab libsvm](https://sites.google.com/site/kittipat/libsvm_matlab)

Comment: Zoran and Alexandre thanks for your help and I will have a look at the LibSVM website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To look at the "training error" just apply the model to the training data. 
Assuming you use the standard Matlab data:

```
load fisheriris
xdata = meas(51:end,3:4);
group = species(51:end);
model = svmtrain(xdata, group);
```

use the svmclassify on the data:

```
predictions = svmclassify(model, xdata);
```

then compute the the fraction of misclassified data:

```
disp( [group predictions ] )
```